# Duplicate Elements in Array (SML)

Tags: list, sml

I have the following list

```
L = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

and I am trying to write a function that duplicates each element in the list, so the end result would be

```
L = [2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 10, 10]
```

where my function is

```
fun duplicateList(nil) = nil
  | duplicateList([a]) = [a]
  | duplicateList(L) = 
       let val copy = L
       in hd(L)::hd(copy)::duplicateList(tl(L))
       end;
```

But I keep getting an error that reads `Error: syntax error: replacing END with EQUALOP`

What does that mean and how can I avoid it?

Comment: It works pasted into `sml` for me (well, it has a bug, but not a syntax error). Is that all your code?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error by evalutating your function declaration. Using `Standard ML of New Jersey v110.77`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your function as follows

```
fun duplicateList nil = nil
  | duplicateList (x::xs) = x :: x :: duplicateList xs;
```

This way you aren't making the copy and you only have to worry about two cases.

Comment: Your code worked! Thank you :) One thing though, I had to modify it for another case in `duplicateList([a]) = a :: [a]` to make sure the last element of the list is duplicated.

Comment: @mynorka you could simply leave out that clause .. what James wrote will work

Comment: To further explain what @RasmusWL means.  Consider the list `[a]` which is also represented as `a :: nil`.  This matches the `(x::xs)` pattern with x=a and xs=nil.  The function yields `a :: a :: duplicateList nil` which simplifies to `a :: a :: nil` also written as `[a,a]`

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do something like below:

```
val L = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
val D = foldr (fn (a, b) => a::a::b) [] L
```